# Is the London pass valid(/free) for multiple entries to same tourist attraction?

Tags: london, sightseeing, tips-and-tricks, history

I am planning to buy 10 a day London pass to visit all the attractions in London. Can I enter into the same attraction, such as the Thames River Cruise, multiple times with this London pass, without paying entry fee second time?

**UPDATE after using London Pass:**
Collected London pass after showing email on phone. Using London pass, collected City cruise 24 hour ticket at 2PM and boarded once on same day and second time next day morning too. Seen one tourist, showing London pass email on phone at Windsor castle to get entry without the actual London pass tag.

What a great city London is!!! I wonder why London is not part of 7 world wonders.

Comment: Can you link us to the website or whatever of this pass - there's lots of this kind of thing. Note that many of the big museums are free to enter for anybody (pass or not) all the time - although they often have "premium" exhibitions inside.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [How does the London Pass work?](http://www.londonpass.com/how-it-works/):

> Note: Passes can only be used at each attraction once.

However, [as noted by JakubJ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49392), for the Thames boat trip, [what you actually get](http://www.londonpass.com/london-attractions/thames-river-boat-cruise.html) is

> #### Make the most of your London Pass:
>
> - Free 24 hour hop-on, hop-off cruise ticket worth over £18

So for this attraction (alone), you get as many trips as you like, within a single 24 hour period.

So given that the Thames River Cruise is listed as one of the attractions, I'd say the answer is **no** to both your questions.

Comment: You should change the info in your answer regarding the boat cruise, if you are talking about the same boat cruise as @JakubJ

Answer (score 15):

Regarding the attractions - it is not possible.

But regarding **the Boat cruise**, you actually can enter it multiple times. You will receive 1-day ticket (see http://www.londonpass.com/london-attractions/thames-river-boat-cruise.html) and within those 24 hours, you can use it multiple times. I was there last year, activated the 24-hour ticket in the afternoon and next day morning, it was still valid.